# Python 3 - Email appears as "..." in HTML downloaded page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, httprequest

I need to get the emails from pages like this: http://bari.geometriapulia.net/index.php/albo-lista/userprofile/abbatantuono-giuseppe

To do that I use the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

url = "http://bari.geometriapulia.net/index.php/albo-lista/userprofile/abbatantuono-giuseppe"

content = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

for link in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r"^mailto:")):

    if "@" in str(link.string):            
        print(link.string)
```

This code does not find the emails I want, wich are the two you can see under the profile picture, but it finds the email that is placed on the bottom of the page (not of my interest).

To try to understand why, I downloaded the whole HTML page, and where there should be the emails you can read the "..." where the mail should be, and also a warning in the line under it:

```
<td class="fieldCell" id="cbfv_84"><span class="cbMailRepl" id="cbMa92357">...</span><noscript> 
This e-mail address is protected by spam bot, you must activate JavaScript in you browser in order to visualize it
</noscript>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="sectiontableentry2 cbft_emailaddress" id="cbfr_97">
<td class="titleCell"><label for="cbfv_97" id="cblabcbfv_97">e-mail:</label></td>
<td class="fieldCell" id="cbfv_97"><span class="cbMailRepl" id="cbMa92358">...</span><noscript> 
 This e-mail address is protected by spam bot, you must activate JavaScript in you browser in order to visualize it
```

So I checked if my JavaScript was enabled in my browser and it already was as you can see from this screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/dwgl7w

So how can I download the page without getting the mail "clipped out" from the HTML code by the anti-spam bot system?
Is this even possible?

Comment: Your browser has nothing to do with this protocol.
Since this page isn't built to be accessed by a python script in the first place, this text is very misleading.

The script you are using is acting like a user, accessing the site and reading it. At this moment, your script is asked to perform a certain task, to run a little javascript script, a simple captcha I guess. Since your script isn't able to run the js-script it is correctly detected and handled.

Answer (score 0):

The email address is generated by JavaScript:
[image]

`requests` or `urllib` can not hanlde JS code. Use selenium.

Comment: With that Im getting the mails on the bottom of the page, but I want the one above it, like I sad in my original post: http://prntscr.com/dwrjs7